# what is the volume of Cloudera CDH3 for 50 nodes

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

The free version only support limited 50 nodes.
If I use 10 times 2T hard disk for one computer. That means 10*2*50 = 1000T
I could save 1000T data, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't replicate your data this is true.

Usually in a 50 node environment your replication is set to 3 or 4. 
Which then will reduce your amount of **unique** data stored to 1000T/3 = 33T or to 1000T/4 = 250T.

Comment: CRC CheckSums (4 bytes for every 512 bytes) takes less than 1% of the space which is the major overhead. Then there is the OS and others which are minor.

Comment: You might also want to use some of your disk for your OS and for system logs -- since you won't get much support if you don't keep good logs